# How can I insert multiple pictures in a beamer foil?

Tags: beamer, graphics, diagrams, presentations

I want to implement the slide shown below in beamer [image: here].Please let me know how I should go about this.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this?

[image]

Code

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{minipage}[c]{.4\linewidth}
  some text
\end{minipage}\hfill
\begin{minipage}[c]{.4\linewidth}
  \raggedleft\includegraphics[width=.5\linewidth]{example-image-a}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[c]{.4\linewidth}
  \includegraphics[width=.5\linewidth]{example-image-b}
\end{minipage}\hfill
\begin{minipage}[c]{.4\linewidth}
  \raggedleft some text
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[c]{.4\linewidth}
  some text
\end{minipage}\hfill
\begin{minipage}[c]{.4\linewidth}
  \raggedleft\includegraphics[width=.5\linewidth]{example-image-c}
\end{minipage}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

or like this (adjust the spacing inside `\vspace*` to your need)?

[image]

Code

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{minipage}[c]{.4\linewidth}
  some text
\end{minipage}\hfill
\begin{minipage}[c]{.4\linewidth}
  \raggedleft\includegraphics[width=.5\linewidth]{example-image-a}
\end{minipage}
\par\vspace*{-.5\baselineskip}
\begin{minipage}[c]{.4\linewidth}
  \includegraphics[width=.5\linewidth]{example-image-b}
\end{minipage}\hfill
\begin{minipage}[c]{.4\linewidth}
  \raggedleft some text
\end{minipage}
\par\vspace*{-.5\baselineskip}
\begin{minipage}[c]{.4\linewidth}
  some text
\end{minipage}\hfill
\begin{minipage}[c]{.4\linewidth}
  \raggedleft\includegraphics[width=.5\linewidth]{example-image-c}
\end{minipage}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```